# Joining two models together to access in view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, linq

I have 2 models, `Project` and `Client`. Within the data model, they join on a common field called `ClientID` - a project has a unique `ProjectID` identifier, and joins to the primary key of the Client table (`Client ID`) to obtain specific client-level information for each project.

Within my `MainData` viewmodel, I am initialising an IEnumerable of the Project model (which is used in the view), and want to join it onto the `Client` model to obtain a field under `Client` called `ReviewOffice`. When I try to define a custom property under `Project` (called `Office`), it has a severe impact on performance due to it looping through each item in my `ProjectList` object.

Is there a more efficient way for me to obtain the `ReviewOffice` property under `Client`?

**Project.vb**

```
Partial Public Class Project
    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    Public Property ProjectID As Integer

    Public Property ClientID As Integer

    <NotMapped>
    Public Property Office As String
End Class
```

**Client.vb**

```
Partial Public Class Client
    Public Property ClientID As Integer
    Public Property ReviewOffice As String
End Class
```

**MainData.vb** (ViewModel)

```
Public Property ProjectList As IEnumerable(Of Project)

Using db As New DatabaseContext
    ProjectList = (From p In db.Projects Select p)  

    If Not IsNothing(ProjectList)
        For Each prj In ProjectList
            prj.Office = (From c In db.Clients Where prj.ClientID = c.ClientID Select c.ReviewOffice).FirstOrDefault
        Next prj
    End If
End Using
```